# VBS Compare strings using wildcard

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a vbscript function that requires a string comparison where one/both strings may include a wildcard.  Unfortunately, `strcomp("string1","string.*")=0` does not work for me as it is doing a comparison and seeing the `.*` regex wildcard as a literal and not a wildcard.

How do I go about comparing two strings where one and/or both include a wildcard?

Function:

```
Function webtableCheck(pageName, tableProperty, rowNum, colNum, checkValue)
   Dim x, y, oD, oC
    x = split(tableProperty,":=")
   If checkValue <> "" Then
        Set oD = description.Create
        oD("micclass").value = "WebTable"
        oD(x(0)).value = x(1)
        Set oC = pageName.childobjects(oD)
        y = oC(0).getcelldata(rowNum, colNum)
        msgbox(y)
        If y=checkValue Then
            reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "WebTable Checkpoint", "The webtable checkpoint object """ &  checkValue & """ was found."
        Elseif  **strcomp(y,checkValue,1)** = 0 Then
            reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "WebTable Checkpoint", "The webtable checkpoint object """ &  checkValue & """ was found, however the casing does not match."
        Elseif strcomp(trim(y),trim(checkValue)) = 0 Then
            reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "WebTable Checkpoint", "The webtable checkpoint object """ &  checkValue & """ was found, however leading/lagging spaces not included in datatable and/or webtable cell was found."
        Elseif instr(1,y,checkValue,1) Then
            reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "WebTable Checkpoint", "The webtable checkpoint object """ &  checkValue & """ was found., however a line break or other hidden character was found in the webtable."
        Else
            reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "WebTable Checkpoint", "The webtable checkpoint object """ &  checkValue & """ was not found."
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression, here an example.

```
line = "this is the text to look in to, it contains the searchpattern"
Set RE = New RegExp
RE.IgnoreCase = True
RE.Pattern = "search.*tern"
If RE.Test(Line) Then WScript.echo "found"
```

The .* is a regularexpression, . stands for any character, * stands for none or multiple occurences of the previous, you could also use .+ here where the + meanbs at least one occurence.
You can find a multitude examples and sourcematerial about regular expressions on the internet, only take in account Vbscript uses a not so standard form so be sure to include that in your search.

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/24/Regular-Expressions-and-VBScript

http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscriptexample.html